# Dart Using IS Operator to check Generic Type

Tags: generics, dart

I having some problem in checking the type of my variable when it is generic.

Example `T` is `List<MyClass>`

```
T is List<MyClass>
//return false
T is List
//return false
```

In the end, I have to use some stupid method in order to get the correct answer

```
T.toString() == "List<MyClass>"
//return true
```

Is there any standard way to deal with it, or I need to stick with my stupid method until official release?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a case where `T is List<MyClass>` fails when `T` actually is `List<MyClass>`.

Answer (score 8):

I made the "T is SomeClass" mistake before. T is a class so the "is" won't work on it.

On elements you should use `T == MyClass`.

On lists you should instantiate a List e.g. `List<MyClass>() is T`.

This is not a clean solution but `List<MyClass> == T` and `List<MyClass>() == T` won't work. Unfortunatly until now I did not figure out any better solution. Hope it works.

Comment: What if `T` is a runtimeType? E.g. `Type t = (<int>[]).runtimeType` is a `List<int>` - how can I check for this type? And is what you mention about instantiating true for all classes with a generic type?